# Simulate correlated variables limiting deviations between observed and defined correlation coefficients

Tags: r, simulation, correlation, normal-distribution

```
    dev_allowance <- 0.15 #Deviation in r allowed
    within_limit <- FALSE #Initiate
    count <- 0            #Loop count
    nvar <- 10            #number of variables to simulate
    nobs = 50             #number of observations to simulate
    #define correlation matrix
    M = matrix(c(1., .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0,
                 .0, 1., .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, 1., .8, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, .8, 1., .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, .0, .0, 1., .2, .0, .0, .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, .0, .0, .2, 1., .0, .0, .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, 1., .8, .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .8, 1., .0, .0,
                 .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, 1., .2,
                 .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .0, .2, 1.), nrow=nvar, ncol=nvar)
    L = chol(M)           # Cholesky decomposition

    #Loop while not within limit
    while (!within_limit) {
      # Generate random variables
        r = t(L) %*% matrix(rnorm(nvars*nobs), nrow=nvars, ncol=nobs)
        r = t(r)
      # Check if within limit
        within_limit <- all(abs(cor(r) - M) < dev_allowance)
      # Count loop
        count <- count + 1
    }

    cat(paste0("run count: ", count))
```

I am trying to simulate some 10 random normal variables with defined correlations. Meanwhile, I want the correlation of the simulated variables to be within a certain range centered at the defined correlation.

But the run time is unacceptably, if not infinitely, long.

For now, I want to do `nobs=50` and `nobs=200`. While I planned to set `dev_allowance=0.05`, what I have now is it can take more than a minute when `dev_allowance` is less than approx. 0.16 for `nobs=50` and approx. 0.08 for `nobs=200`. Not dare to try smaller `dev_allowance`...

Is there a workaround if I am to stick to this current scheme of parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... half-way through typing the question this came into my mind:

```
    sim_nvar <- matrix(rnorm(nobs), ncol=nobs)
    for (i in 2:nvar) {
      within_limit <- FALSE
      while (!within_limit) {
        #Generate random variables
          sim_var <- t(L)[i, 1:i] %*% rbind(sim_nvar, matrix(rnorm(nobs), ncol=nobs))
          sim_var <- t(rbind(sim_nvar, sim_var))
        #Check if within limit
          within_limit <- all(abs(cor(sim_var) - M[1:i, 1:i]) < dev_allowance)
      }
      sim_nvar <- t(sim_var)
    }
    sim_nvar <- t(sim_nvar)

    all(abs(cor(sim_nvar) - M) < dev_allowance)
    [1] TRUE
```

It seems okay to me. But is there any flaw if I separate the simulation this way? Or is it the best way yet?

Comment: what seems odd at first glance is that you keep calling `rnorm` instead of trying to re-order draws that you already have